# Magento 2 observer for sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento-2.1

I observe the event sales_order_place_after
If I buy like guest or new user `custumer name, lastname` is NULL if I buy logged name, lastname is normal

```
$observer->getOrder()->getCustomerFirstname();
```

I use Magento 2.1.11

How fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution

```
$Order =$observer->getOrder();

    if($Order->getCustomerIsGuest())
    { // if  customer is guest
    $firstname = $Order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname = $Order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname()
    }else{
       $firstname = $Order->getCustomerFirstname();
    $lastname = $Order->getCustomerLastname()
    }
```

Comment: @Andszej, please accept the answer. So it will help to others.